# Need a fast programming language that can drive two printers

Tags: windows, printing

I have a rather unusual application that isn't working the way I need, and I hope someone here will have some suggestions or at least a direction to investigate.

We have a museum exhibit that has a computer at the entrance driving two small receipt printers. There are two buttons on a console, wired to the left and right buttons of a disemboweled mouse. The two printers and associated buttons are for girls and boys, each button does a random selection from a database of names and prints a small ticket on the appropriate printer with a graphic image, a few words about the exhibit and the randomly chosen name.

Conceptually all is well, but it hangs quite often. I got the project at the last minute, because the original designer got bogged down and couldn't deliver, so the exhibit's author asked me the day before opening, whether I could write something that would work.

I did it in Word, since I am an experienced VBA programmer. Several other avenues I attempted first all lead to dead ends - one couldn't do graphics, another couldn't handle two printers, yet another couldn't change fonts and so on. The problem is that it simply isn't fast enough - Word can only drive one printer at a time and changing the active printer takes a long time. Not by office standards, where a second or two of delay before a printer starts working on your document is not an issue, but here I need more or less instant response. If kids press a button and nothing happens, they press it over and over until something does happen, resulting in maybe half a dozen commands being sent before the printer starts reacting. Sometimes it jams the program completely, since boys and girls will be pressing the two buttons simultaneously and Word locks up, and even when it doesn't jam, the printers then spit out a stream of tickets, making a mess. The kids start squabbling over which ticket is whose, pulling them out of the printers, snarling the paper tape, jamming the printer and generally making a mess of the whole affair, often necessitating the exhibit caretakers having to restart the computer and clear torn bits of paper out the printers.

What I need is some sort of **fast** programming language that can drive two printers ****-simultaneously-****, not the MSOffice claptrap of having to switch the active printer, that can react to both left and right mouse button click events, can print a small graphic image and can print in different font sizes and styles and. I don't need many, but it's not all in one typeface.

Can anyone suggest what I might use for this? I don't even know if it's possible at all under Windows, whether the "single active printer" garbage is an Office artifact, or a Windows restriction. My little Commodore-64 twenty-five years ago had two printers attached to it and drove both simultaneously with no difficulties - it doesn't seem to me it should be such an impossible requirement today.

Comment: A temporary solution would be to block any requests until the current is served. And of course add some info that a request is processed, if possible. What i do not understand is why there are two printers?

Comment: One for boys, one for girls. Schools often organize field trips here and there can be maybe twenty kids crowding around this console at once. Even two printers are busy, and if one were giving out both boys and girls tickets, confusion would increase a lot. This way at least each kid gets the correct sort of name, even if not necessarily exactly the one for which he/she actually pressed the button.

Comment: As for the blocking, do you know how I might do that? What sometimes happens is that Word's built-in right-click menus appear when the code can't process quickly enough, and subsequent clicks hit that, instead of the command button to activate the printing code. I suspect this is an occasional source of hangups, although there is no monitor normally attached to this machine, so I'm not always sure  exactly what caused a hang. There is no way to tell kids that a request is being processed - the only visual feedback is printing the ticket.

Answer (score 3):

Being a Python programmer myself, I would use something like [MSWinPrint.py](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/mswinprint.html), and render the documents directly using Python. It looks like it supports text and images, and you can easily select any printer in the system by name.

You would need to:

1. Install [Python](http://python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/).
2. Install [Python for Windows Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).
3. Install [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).
4. Install [MSWinPrint](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/mswinprint.html).

Then, you would need to write a program to do the printing. Something like the following.

```
#python
import sys
import Image, ImageWin
import MSWinPrint

# workaround for PIL namespace change
MSWinPrint.ImageWin = ImageWin

def print_name(name, printer_name):
    doc = MSWinPrint.document(printer_name)
    doc.begin_document('nametag for %s' % name)
    # print the name at position 20,20
    text_pos = 20, 20
    doc.text(text_pos, name)
    # add an image for this person
    img_pos = 40, 40
    img_size = 100, 100
    doc.image(img_pos, get_image(), img_size)
    doc.end_document()

def get_image():
    image_filename = 'my image.jpg'
    return Image.open(image_filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name, printer_name = sys.argv[1:]
    print_name(name, printer_name)
```

If you save this as `print_tag.py`, then you can execute it with two command line arguments, the name to be printed and the image filename.

```
print_tag.py Sally "EPSON Artisan 810"
```

I ran this code and it worked great. I didn't know creating a custom print job could be so easy.

You can of course run the program as often as you like on as many printers as you would like. There's certainly more you can do to customize when an how the print job is run. You could customize the code to always run and interpret the mouse clicks (for that you might need wxPython), or you might have another program that just executes the script.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I've never worked with Python before, but have been meaning to give it a whirl. This looks like a good time to try.  I've managed a stopgap in the meantime: the first command in the code is to disable the command button and leave it that way while all the code executes, including the active printer switch. Last thing, just before exiting, I re-enable the button. The response time is no better, but this at least keeps mouse clicks from queueing up while the code is busy and maybe prevents some lockups and crashes. So far, at least, it's working.

Answer (score 2):

As other have said, the programming language isn't going to make much difference.  However (and this is a BIG however), the print libraries built into most scripting languages, such as VBA and .NET, either only support printing to the system default printer (most common, and cannot be worked around by having two instances open simultaneously, as the system default printer is a global setting) or require you to configure a global variable to specify the active printer (this only affects one process, so could be worked around using two instances).

Instead, you will have to invoke the windows API directly.  It most certainly allows printing directly to any printer on the system.  [Here is an example of how to use the default printer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183521.aspx)  Note that only one line of code (calling the `GetDefaultPrinter` function) ties this to the default printer.  Supplying a different printer name to `CreateDC` gets you a different printer.

If you instead call the [`EnumPrinters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162692.aspx) function, you can find out ANY or ALL of the printer names, not just the default.  Or have the administrator preconfigure the printer names to use in a registry setting or text file.

In any case, you can have device contexts for all printers open simultaneously.  Of course, once you have the printer device context, you have to create a print job, send your content, and end the print job.  There's [a great deal of information available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg263344.aspx).

All the examples are in C, which makes C++ the obvious language for printing to non-default printers, but as long as you know how to call WinAPI functions from your language, you can use it instead.  In VBA, that'd require `Declare Function XYZ Lib "gdi32" (params here)`

Comment: Thank you, Ben, this looks promising. I'm not a C or C++ programmer, but I've had to learn dozens of languages over the years and my application is a pretty trivial task - if I can't manage it in VBA, I can probably muddle together something in C that will work, even  though it would likely have language purists loading their shotguns. I'll look this over and post back what I manage from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the programming language, its just a limitation of the printer stack you are using.

I am not sure if .NET would support it (or Windows for that matter) would support sending printing on a thread. You could put each printer in its own thread and block the UI from accepting more print requests.

You could also try to turn on print spooling for both printers. That will render it locally and return then print.

Comment: I don't follow - VBA in all Office apps has ONE active printer. When you issue a print command, output gets sent to that single active printer, no matter how many are physically attached or networked to the computer. How is that not a language limitation, and more importantly, do you know of a way around it?

Comment: I have spooling turned on already. I tried turning it off and printing directly, hoping for faster response, but it wasn't any faster, just more prone to hanging, so I turned it back on.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with .NET to understand the thread concept. Can you point me at a tutorial or some such?

Comment: Threads are a programming concept. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)

Comment: I wonder if I might be able to do the same thing in Word? Open a master document that would react to the button presses, then two more documents, each with one of the printers as its active printer. Then the master could send messages to the two slaves, who would immediately print to their own printer, without having to switch active printers, which is the most time-consuming part of the code.

Comment: I would avoid doing applications in VBA.

Comment: @Pete: If VBA is what you know, and you have to deliver fast, I bet it can be done. I have personally done quite "unorthodox" things with VBA, it is actually not as limited as it sounds. Note that VB6 is similar, and might be better suited, though.

Comment: What then? Is .NET a stand-alone, that can generate an executable file, with graphic interface that can react to mouse button clicks? Do I need Visual Studio or some such to create those?

I don't mean to be snippy, but simply telling me that you don't like VBA isn't much help. I'm looking for concrete advice on how to DO something, not remarks that what I did isn't so hot - I already know that, that's why I'm here looking for advice.

Comment: .NET is a framework that you can use Microsoft Visual Studio to develop applications that run on it.

Comment: Øystein - I agree. I've been programming in VBA for over a decade and have a library full of 'impossible' accomplishments. But I'm stuck here on the response time and single printer issue. I have an app that works, but it's not robust enough for the environment.

Comment: Daniel - And does .NET allow simultaneous control of two printers? If I have to ask the OS for a redirect, it will probably make little difference if the request comes from VBA or .NET. Do you -KNOW- whether I can do what I need with it?

Comment: @Pete: .NET allows simultaneous control of two printers, but it doesn't make any easier than VBA does.  All you need is any languages that provides a way to call into GDI32.DLL directly.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something a few years ago (in VB6 so could probably be ported to VBA easily) that bypassed the printer driver (a printer must be set up but the actual driver used was irrelevant) and sent raw commands to the printer. Depending on what sort of printer you are using this may or may not be an issue (some use complex escape sequences). If you want to print graphics, this could add another layer of complication - although it can be done if you know what commands the printer supports. I managed to get bitmaps printing on a dot matrix printer, but it wasn't a 5 minute task. If this is something you are interested in I can try and dig out the code?

The Code is as follows:

```
Public Type DOCINFO
          pDocName As String
          pOutputFile As String
          pDatatype As String
      End Type

Declare Function ClosePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long

Declare Function EndDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long

Declare Function EndPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long

Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, phPrinter As Long, ByVal pDefault As Long) As Long

Declare Function StartDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "StartDocPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal Level As Long, pDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long

Declare Function StartPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long

Declare Function WritePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, pBuf As Any, ByVal cdBuf As Long, pcWritten As Long) As Long

Public Function PrintRawData(ByVal sPrinter As String, ByVal sDocName As String, ByVal sData As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo PrintErr:

          Dim lhPrinter As Long, lReturn As Long, lpcWritten As Long
          Dim lDoc As Long, sWrittenData As String
          Dim MyDocInfo As DOCINFO
          Dim pOutput As Printer
          Dim p As Printer

            For Each p In Printers
                If p.DeviceName = sPrinter Then
                    Set pOutput = p
                    GoTo StartPrinting
                End If
            Next p

            MsgBox "Unable to find the specified printer [" & sPrinter & _
            "] in the list of currently installed printers" & vbCrLf & _
            "Printing will be aborted", vbCritical
            Exit Function

StartPrinting:
          lReturn = OpenPrinter(pOutput.DeviceName, lhPrinter, 0)

          If lReturn = 0 Then
              MsgBox "Print was unsuccessful. Make sure there is a printer installed on the port you are trying to print to"
              Exit Function
          End If

          MyDocInfo.pDocName = sDocName
          MyDocInfo.pOutputFile = vbNullString
          MyDocInfo.pDatatype = vbNullString
          lDoc = StartDocPrinter(lhPrinter, 1, MyDocInfo)
          Call StartPagePrinter(lhPrinter)

          sWrittenData = sData

          lReturn = WritePrinter(lhPrinter, ByVal sWrittenData, Len(sWrittenData), lpcWritten)
          lReturn = EndPagePrinter(lhPrinter) 'need this??
          lReturn = EndDocPrinter(lhPrinter)
          lReturn = ClosePrinter(lhPrinter)

          Exit Function

PrintErr:
    MsgBox "Print was unsuccessful. Make sure there is a printer installed on the port you are trying to print to"
    Exit Function

End Function
```

To use it you need to install a printer that uses the correct port using any driver (I generally use the Generic / text Only Driver) and then call it as follows replacing the Hello with the data you want to send to the printer including control characters etc:

```
PrintRawData "Generic / Text Only", "My Document", "Hello"
```

Comment: I do need a small graphic image and unfortunately, have no idea how to feed that to these printers. I could look into it, if your code would speed up the rest of it. If you want to send it to me directly, I'd be happy to have a look and see what I can do with it. My email name is 'pdanes' and I use Yahoo mail. Or if it's short enough to post here, that would be great as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated and completely overhauled Answer* :

**Pete, have you considered an entirely different kind of printer?** The setting, changing and sending PostSCript commands can take, indeed, a lot of time.

A strange solution you might call it, but our instant B/W laser Brother label printer prints out instantly on a press of the button. Their specialty rock solid in house developed P-Touch Editor 5.4 Software is created in such a way as **to output to multiple printers simeltaneously(!!)**, each printing the same or different lables (for example different serial numbers or dates from a database).

Its snappy: when letting go of a return button, just when my finger has reached half a centimeter in the button already IIIIEEEUUUUUU (1 second after release of return key) the entire lable is out. Albeit in black and white.

Aside lables there are also paper lables without sticky backs 102mm wide rols by either original or third party brands makes.

Cost: 100$ ~ 400$ per unit incl software to design and customise connections with database.

I know that those instant printers use much less windows-based drivers and more embedded technologies, relieving the system from standardized print jobs.

Perhaps this solves your problem or brings you on a new idea.

Comment: There's no indication that the printer is too slow, in fact the strong implication from the question is that delivering all output to just one printer is plenty fast.  But he needs output in two places at once.

Comment: Yes, the program is trivial and executes almost instantly, printers are also quick, once they get started. What's slow is the switching of the ACTIVE printer from one to the other, and that seems to be a Windows limitation, from all I've been able to gather. I even tried opening two documents and each having its own printer, but switching it in one document also switches the other. I may wind up having to install another computer, one for each printer. That seems like a completely retarded thing to have to do, but I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @Pete I have updated my old answer! Especialy the section about simultaneous printing to multiple printers at once triggered me to your question which was asked 10+ years ago. I was curious if you have already found a solution.